# Q: AWS Lambda boto3 iot delete_job not implemented?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-iot

The boto3 documentation describes a function to delete a job. See: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.delete_job

I have written a Lambda that can successfully create_job, cancel_job, and list_job_executions_for_thing. The delete_job function doesn't work.

Using the example from the boto3 documentation:

```
client=boto3.client('iot')
    response = client.delete_job(
    jobId='Upgrade00003',
    force=True
)
```

Gives the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'IoT' object has no attribute 'delete_job'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      162,
      "lambda_handler",
      "response = client.delete_job("
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      555,
      "__getattr__",
      "self.__class__.__name__, item)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

"iot:DeleteJob" also does not show up as an option in the IAM Role permissions.

Is the delete_job boto3 function not implemented by AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and got the same error, but then upgraded `boto3`:

```
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

The resulting version was:

```
Successfully installed boto3-1.7.34 botocore-1.10.34
```

The `delete_job()` command now works.

Comment: Unfortunately this project is an AWS Lambda, so I don't think that I can upgrade the version of boto3 that AWS provides.

Comment: If needed, you can possibly package it into your code.

Comment: I just checked and the default boto3 version in a Lambda is: 1.7.14.
I will load the 1.7.34 with the Lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding newer boto3 to the Lambda code enabled delete_job(), but unfortunately the package is now to big to support inline editing.